# Page Admin Blank page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

Hello I have a problem with my admin page, I have the connection chart but just after I have a blank page and nothing helps I can't find a solution I tried everything as per example this:

In vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php
inside this function, I modified the following line...

```
$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
```

with this line:

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

Update :

Here is a screenshot
[image]

and here a screenshot of the php modules:
[image]
[image]

it would be nice if you help me thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

After changing the above line have you re-deployed, try the following command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: Hi,I have already done nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
{
      $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
      if (!is_array($directories)) {
         $directories = (array)$directories;
      }

    foreach ($directories as $directory) {
       if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
          return true;
       }
}
return false;
```

}
check this code if it is working for you

Comment: Hello, idem is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Please once again verify these PHP extension enable or not
In php.ini enable php extension

sodium,
ext-bcmath,
ext-ctype,
ext-curl,
ext-dom,
ext-gd,
ext-hash,
ext-iconv,
ext-intl,
ext-mbstring,
ext-openssl,
ext-pdo_mysql,
ext-simplexml,
ext-soap,
ext-xsl,
ext-zip
ext-sockets if not then enable it.
After enable plz run all the command and then check it is working or not

Second one plz try in these 3 files:

vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2.php

```
private function validateURLScheme(string $filename) : bool
{
  $allowed_schemes = ['ftp', 'ftps', 'http', 'https'];
  $url = parse_url($filename);
  if ($url && isset($url['scheme']) && !in_array($url['scheme'], $allowed_schemes) && !file_exists($filename)) {
      return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

vendor/magento/framework/view/element/template/file/validator.php with this.

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
{
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
if (!is_array($directories)) {
    $directories = (array)$directories;
}

foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Magento/Framework/Interception/PluginListGenerator.php

```
$cacheId = implode('-', $this->scopePriorityScheme) . "-" . $this->cacheId;
```

Plz update these three files and check, Hope it will work for you.

Comment: @primalon it is working or not

Comment: I can't find the file PluginListGenerator.php in this path Magento/Framework/Interception/

Comment: I tried with the two files which are modified still nothing

Comment: check this path line number 156 vendor\magento\framework\Interception\PluginListGenerator.php

Comment: the file PluginListGenerator.php does not exist  in vendor\magento\framework\Interception\

Comment: Hello, I tried with the two modified files it did nothing